# Rendering data charts are built but not displayed in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, dc.js

I have a very simple ASPX page that references d3.js, crossfilter.js, and dc.js.
It also references my javascript library for the page.
I'm also using Ext.js (our company standard).
I have this in my aspx page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="c" runat="server">
    <ext:Container runat="server">
        <Content>
    <div class="container" align="center" runat="server">

        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="soi-chart">
                <strong>SOI</strong>
                <a class="reset" href="javascript:soiChart.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();" style="display: none;">reset</a>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
```

I can see the Heading and SOI label on the page. I can also debug through the javascript and I've verified that the data is being loaded. my javascript contains:

```
var soiChart = dc.pieChart('#soi-chart');
d3.csv('LOSOpportunity.csv').then(function (data) {
    var soi = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.SOI;
    });
    // Produce counts records in the dimension
    var soiGroup = soi.group();

    soiChart
        .width(240)
        .height(180)
        .radius(80)
        .dimension(soi)
        .group(soiGroup)
        .label(function (d) {
            if (soiChart.hasFilter() && !soiChart.hasFilter(d.key)) {
                return d.key + '(0%)';
            }
            var label = d.key;
            if (all.value()) {
                label += '(' + Math.floor(d.value / all.value() * 100) + '%)';
            }
            return label;
        });
    dc.renderAll();
});
```

However, when the page renders, I only see the labels, and none of the graphs are being rendered. If I examine the href for the graph step by stop

```
javascript:soiChart.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();
```

it doesn't stop at any exceptions, and, I find that dc.redrawAll() doesn't make any difference. dc.version returns 3.0.6 in the debugger;

Comment: This isn't quite enough information for us to help you debug. But I understand if it's difficult to create a self contained example. Do you get any errors in the browser debug console? Are you sure that the code within the d3.csv callback is being run? You are using d3 v5 right?

Comment: I'll just bet this was the classic d3v3 d3-request vs d3v5 d3-fetch issue. Love it when APIs change to create silent failures.